# Stop a website redirecting to my website

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have a rogue website that is redirecting to my website. It doesn't have any content, 1 page, and some bad backlinks and no relationship with us or our niche, so it's safe to say its up to no good.

We want to distance ourselved from this as best as possible. I've requested that the registrar identify the culprit or remove the redirect, however, I wondered if it was possible to stop the site redirecting to our site full-stop.

We're using IIS7.5 on a Windows 2008 Server, and to date I've looked at blocking requests through urlrewriting but I've had no success. I've also read that request filtering may be an option but again little knowledge as to the capabilities of using this.

I would appreciate any advice regarding the 2 approaches above as to whether they are suited to what I want to achieve and if possible links to a clear example.

Comment: I'm not posting an answer because I don't know how to do this on IIS, but most browsers will include a `Referer` (sic) header telling you the URL they've come from; you could test for this and respond appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817802/check-http-referer-on-a-windows-server) that covers this exact topic. You will need to use URL Rewrite to implement the solution.

Comment: The post covers hotlinking - I'm looking at stopping an entire site.